# SQL Server 2017 and online index rebuild not working after Standard to Enterprise upgrade

Tags: sql-server, indexing, rebuild

I've upgraded from Standard Edition to Enterprise Edition, which is shown correctly:

```
Enterprise Edition (64-bit)
```

If I try to modify an index (or recreate) I no longer get an error that it's only supported on Enterprise Edition. Which is good, but it doesn't apply the ONLINE = ON part.

For example:

```sql
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NonClusteredIndex-Test] ON [dbo].[Test]
(
    [Name] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = ON, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

After the index is created, ONLINE remains on OFF. I've been experimenting with various index options, all are applied, but ONLINE = ON doesn't work. Is there something I'm missing or need to modify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ONLINE is not an attribute of the index itself.  It only applies to the CREATE or ALTER statement that is building/rebuilding the index.

For instance you might build the index with ONLINE=ON during business hours, but choose to rebuild it with ONLINE=OFF during an outage window.

Comment: Hello David, thank you for the reply. I am creating the index, and, if I understand correctly, this ONLINE option is the same as "Allow online DML processing". I can toggle that through SSMS but it doesn't apply (same as manual create with statement above). Or is this never visible in the UI and is it just for calling rebuild with ONLINE=ON?

Comment: "Allow online DML processing" just sets ONLINE ON or OFF for the index creation or modification you are performing with SSMS.  The "Maximum degree of parallelism" is the same way.  It controls whether the index is created/rebuild with a particular maxdop.  It doesn't change any properties of the index itself.